# Should I make the Apache2 Server treat/see/parse .html files as .php files or not?

Tags: php, html

I've recently started trying to use PHP.

I've installed a Apache2 Server with PHP 7.2 on Linux Mint 19.1.
Then I've added: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` to `mime.conf` so that my server sees .html as PHP.

But I don't know if this is the right way to go.
Currently, I have 2 files in var/www/mysite : index.html and test.php.
I've added `DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

My .html is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<?php include('test.php'); ?>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "master.css">   
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.URR').change(function() {
        var n = $('.URR').val();
        if (n < 1)
            $('.URR').val(1);
        if (n > 10)
            $('.URR').val(10);
    });
    $('.Brightness').change(function() {
        var m = $('.Brightness').val();
        if (m < 2)
            $('.Brightness').val(2);            
        if (m > 99)
            $('.Brightness').val(99);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id = "container">
        <div class = "center-container">
            <div class = "logo"><img url="/logo.png"></div>
            <div class = "title"><h1>Current Settings</h1></div>
            <div id = "center_text_box">
                <p>URL:</p> <p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_URL%</span></p>
                <p>URL Refresh Rate:</p><p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_URR%</span>(s)</p>
                <p>Brightness:</p> <p><span><?php if(isset($Brightness)) print $Brightness; ?></span>(&#37;)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And test.php is this:

```
<?php
// Check if the form is submitted 
if ( isset( $_POST['save_values'] ) ) { // retrieve the form data by using the element's name attributes value as key 
    $Brightness = $_POST['getBrightness'];
    $RefreshRate = $_POST['getRefreshRate'];

} 
?>
```

**Is this a good practice ?**

To have `<?php include('test.php'); ?>` inside a .html file and to use `<?php ?>` tags wherever I need them INSIDE the .html file ?

**Or should I stop parsing .html as .php and instead start generating HTML inside a PHP file by doing:**

```
<?php
$data = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "master.css">   
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.URR').change(function() {
        var n = $('.URR').val();
        if (n < 1)
            $('.URR').val(1);
        if (n > 10)
            $('.URR').val(10);
    });
    $('.Brightness').change(function() {
        var m = $('.Brightness').val();
        if (m < 2)
            $('.Brightness').val(2);            
        if (m > 99)
            $('.Brightness').val(99);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "container">
        <div class = "center-container">
            <div class = "logo"><img url="/logo.png"></div>
            <div class = "title"><h1>Current Settings</h1></div>
            <div id = "center_text_box">
                <p>URL:</p> <p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_URL%</span></p>
                <p>URL Refresh Rate:</p><p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_URR%</span>(s)</p>
                <p>Brightness:</p> <p><span>
"
if(isset($Brightness)) print $Brightness;
$data .= "$Brightness</span>(&#37;)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
"

echo $data;
?>
```

And if the later is the "way to go" can I have more than one .php file to do things ?
And how do they work together ?

Also, will JavaScript or jQuery work from inside `$data` ? Will it work from inside HTML from inside PHP ?

Comment: _“Or should I stop parsing .html as .php and instead start generating HTML inside a PHP file by doing: […]”_ - PHP script files can contain HTML code directly, there is no need to output extended HTML code blocks via PHP in the first place. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: So this means that if I change the extension of `index.html` to `index.php` it will work in the same without forcing the Apache2 server to parse .html into .php ?

Comment: Yes. The file name is only important to let Apache know what to do with this kind of file to begin with - like send it through the PHP parser, or do something else with it. Once PHP starts doing its job, the file name becomes pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Should I keep `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag ? Or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: Yes, because that has nothing to do with PHP in the first place.